# Sending Multiple Sitemap Pings

Tags: sitemap

I'm implementing a sitemap which will be generated based on an event, which I'd like to ping Google with. The issue is that the sitemap will be separately generated on two production machines behind a load balancer. This will work fine, and the two will both generate their sitemaps at roughly the same time.

While I'm well aware that ideally this would run in some sort of other process that would run separately from the individual production machines, that's currently not possible due to other architectural requirements. I've suggested the client invest in a solution to this problem, that will not be complete within the timeframe I have for this.

I would expect that Google would receive the two pings and de-duplicate them, and read the sitemap after some number of seconds after the ping. This would be fine, as both sitemaps would likely be generated by that time.

My options, then, are like this:

1. **Configure only one of the servers to submit the ping** - I'm not a huge fan of this approach, as it leads to configuration differences on the two machines.
2. **Hope for the best** - assuming that Google will de-duplicate the pings and run the request some time after receiving the ping, this would be fine.

Does anyone have experience with this sort of situation?

Answer (score 0):

Your plan is not the recommended way to go if you want to notify Google about new pages. Implement a RSS feed and submit it to https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/. Update the feed with your new pages when necessary.

More info: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/fdD4ZSk9tPw